# Android - Problem with WebView

Tags: android, webview, shapes

I'm pulling my hair around this and have parsed the web several times to understand the following.

I'm using a simple Activity which embeds a WebView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tables"
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to apply a drawable shape (`android:background="@drawable/tables"`) so that the WebView has rounded corners, a stroke border, ...

Problem is that the WebView does not get any of the apparence I'm trying to set (no rounded corners, etc...).

The code of the shape I'm trying to apply :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <solid   android:color="@color/fond_tables"/>
     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
              android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
              android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
              android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
     <stroke  android:width="3dp"
              android:color="@color/bordure_tables" />
</shape>
```

I would be grateful to anyone who could help me solving this issue.

thanks in advance

Adam.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue too. Later I know we can't change the webView background. You can change the layout background. I have tried this method working fine.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"

    android:background="@drawable/fullshape"

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);        
webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

By applying background color transparent, webview will use background from layout.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.